# Pandas adding only two rows inside group

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to add two rows in groups e.g.:

```
ID   DATE   NUMBER 
1   2012-10-11   5 
1   2012-10-12   4 
1   2012-10-13   3 
2   2012-10-11   2 
2   2012-10-12   1 
2   2012-10-13   6
```

I want to add only 2012-10-13 to 2012-10-12. And after that just delete 2012-10-13. Final result:

```
ID   DATE   NUMBER 
1   2012-10-11   5 
1   2012-10-12   7 (4+3) 
2   2012-10-11   2 
2   2012-10-12   7 (6+1)
```

Comment: Is there logic that defines why the last two?  Might it have been the first two in other circumstances?  Is it specific to `2012-10-12` and `2012-10-13`?

Comment: This is only an example. I treat ID as groups. The main issue of that problem is how to add only two rows (with same Date or based on any other column values). I don't want to add all rows for specific group, only those two.

Comment: Yes, but what distinguishes those two?  Will it always be combining `2012-10-12` and `2010-10-13`?  That seems silly to build something that only combines those two dates.  Is it the last two rows in a group?

Comment: Yes, I will always combine those two dates (for this certain problem). There is no special dependence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Specific Date Equivalence

- Use a dictionary to specify the equivalence
- Use `replace` to swap them out
- Use `groupby` as normal

---

```
df.replace({'DATE': {'2012-10-13': '2012-10-12'}}) \
  .groupby(['ID', 'DATE'], as_index=False).sum()

   ID        DATE  NUMBER
0   1  2012-10-11       5
1   1  2012-10-12       7
2   2  2012-10-11       2
3   2  2012-10-12       7
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @piRSquared

Comment: No problem @ArthurG.

Answer (score 1):

```
Import pandas as pd 

## First change the date

for i in range(len(df)): 
    if df.loc[i,'DATE'] == "2012-10-13":
        df.loc[i,'DATE'] = "2012-10-12"

## Then do a groupby sum 

df = pd.DataFrame({'SUM' : df.groupby(['ID','DATE'])['NUMBER'].sum()})
```

my output :

```
               SUM
ID DATE           
1  2012-10-11    5
   2012-10-12    7
2  2012-10-11    2
   2012-10-12    7
```

Comment: That is also a very useful solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: With pleasure @ArthurG

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING : the code above does your job but is NOT evolutive !**

```
# I want to groupby ID excluding the line for 2012-10-11
df1 = df.loc[df.DATE != '2012-10-11']

# 1 - df1.groupby('ID').sum() -> I groupby ID to get the sum
# 2 - df1.drop('NUMBER', axis=1) -> I drop the col NUMBER to avoid overlaping columns
# 3 I merge the to df to get the sum value for every initial lines
df1 = df1.drop('NUMBER', axis=1).merge(df1.groupby('ID').sum(), on='ID')

# I get back the ligne for 2012-10-11
df1 = df1.append(df.loc[df.DATE == '2012-10-11'], sort=True)
df1 = df1.sort_values(['ID', 'DATE'])

# I delete the line I don't want
df1 = df1.loc[df1.DATE != '2012-10-13']

print(df1)
```